# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS x86-64bit Qt Creator 3.0.1 Kit Qt 4.8.6 Failed to start program. Path or Permissions Wrong?

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu

I am trying to run a program in Qt Creator version 3.0.1, compiled on a 64-bit version of Ubuntu 14.04 using Qt 4.8.6.  I have searched through other posts relating to the topic, and odds are that there's a conflict between 32-bit and 64-bit executable files.  However, what is surprising to me is that the program was running just fine with no problems on the exact same environment two hours ago.

The error being returned is:

```
Failed to start program. Path or permissions wrong?
```

Again, I know that there might be a problem with the 32-bit and 64-bit stuff.  I checked the executable with ldd and I got:

```
not a dynamic executable
```

This says to me that the executable cannot be run.  But I still don't know why, because as I said, I was running the program two hours ago and it was working fine.

Comment: Any idea what has changed? Are you trying to run the program via QtCreator (e.g. ctrl+r), or stand alone from a terminal command line `./myProgram`?. You can use the `file` command to tell you if the file is 32-bit or 64-bit...

Comment: I don't really know what's changed.  I've been playing around with sudo apt-get to make sure everything was in order, so maybe something happened in there.

Comment: Can you run the `file` command on your executable? You should get some output like: `$ file program` (where program is your executable), then: `program: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked
    (uses shared libs), stripped` (took that example off a wiki.
Otherwise if its an install issue - could be harder to track, but it might be worth compile/build on a different PC, or even easier a clean ubuntu virtualbox which would only take a couple hours to setup from scratch...

Comment: Also its worth going to your executable and running this manually from the command line/terminal (not within QtCreator) like: `cd /path/to/my/executable/` and then `./program`. If that does not run, check the permissions with (in the same folder) `ls -l` and report back. The file should have permissions to execute... if its a permissions thing then do `chmod 777 program` to give it full permissions + executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact I am fairly sure now that it is one of the following:

Try (where `program` is the name of your executable):

- In a terminal `cd /path/to/your/executable`. Then `./program'

  - If that does not work do `sudo chmod 777 program` and try again.
- If / when you get this running in a terminal try looking in QtCreator build path under `Projects --> General --> Build Directory` and check this path is correct.
- In QtCreator check the `Run Settings --> Working Directory`

It could be that you are running Qt as your normal user when before you where running as admin (or visa versa) and so either your paths have changed or the permissions are different.

I had a look around the web and found similar issues as well, this looks the same to me and I do recall something like this when running as admin once...

Comment: Thank you.  I found that it worked after I did sudo chmod 777.  Your answer has been accepted!

Comment: ah good!, yeah, it suddenly dawned on me - I had problems like these before, especially if using QtCreator with different users on linux platforms... you could look at the user and group with `ls -l` to see which user created the file (i.e. to give you a clue as to what it was you did to "break" the permissions, probably something as sudo - like run QtCreator as sudo, which would break things when you run it as normal user afterwards)...